# How to make base_local_planner tightly follow the global plan?

Tags: navigation, base-local-planner

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

Does anyone know how to configure the base_local_planner provided in the navigation stack (either the trajectory planner or the dwa planner) to tightly follow a given global plan?

I have my own base_global_planner, implemented as a plugin. With the default param setting of "path_distance_bias" and "goal_distance_bias", sometimes the local planner doesn't follow the global plan from the global planner. This is usually because my global planner takes into account things that the local planner is blind of, eg. lane direction. So the global plan is sometimes not the shortest to goal.

I tried setting "goal_distance_bias" very small or even 0, but it just made the local planner stuck - no trajectory is returned. I couldn't find any other parameters that might affect this. Any help or suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30815/how-to-make-base_local_planner-tightly-follow-the-global-plan?/) by [xylo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1185/xylo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 184 on 2012-03-29

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [xylo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1185/xylo/) on 2012-03-29**:
I tried the suggestions in the Navigation Tuning Guide that Eitan wrote, but no luck. Then from the guide I realized, by design the local planner can't tightly follow the global path if the path is very different from the shortest path to goal, due the way its cost function is setup. Is it true?

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2012-06-12**:
maybe you should post your solution as an answer, so it will be easier to others to find that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's fixed by shrinking the local costmap rolling window, so that the global goal lies outside the window.

---

Originally posted by [xylo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1185/xylo/) with karma: 184 on 2012-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3